# How JQuery UI dialog modal attribute is related to css zIndex property?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there any dependency between JQuery UI dialog modal attribute and css zIndex property?

I wanted to know how JQuery UI Dialog modal works to disable the page?

Comment: Quoth the documentation for the [modal](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal) option: `If set to true, the dialog will have modal behavior; other items on the page will be disabled, i.e., cannot be interacted with. Modal dialogs create an overlay below the dialog but above other page elements.`

Comment: Ok.In my application, after setting modal true to dialog, I am changing zIndex property of other item, now that item is enabled even though the modal is being set to dialog. I wanted to know whats happening here exactly?

Comment: Since you have modified the Z index of that element, chances are it lies now above the overlay, so clicks go through and it can be interacted with. I'd suggest you fetch the Z index of the overlay with the developer tools in your browser, and ensure the Z index of your element is always less than that value.